# Getting Stripe Elements form to appear

Tags: javascript, dom, stripe-payments

I am currently working on the example shown [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart)

with the exact same html css and javascript (with the exception of my personal test code). The form from the JS never renders. I am left with a file that only shows a submit button and a "credit or debit card" label. Am I supposed to add an input in the  commented section? I am lost as to why no form will show up when copying this exact example.

```
<div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>
```

For reference, here is how I refactored the code.

**HTML (index.html)**

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="index.js" data-rel-js></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

<form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="card-element">
      Credit or debit card
    </label>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>

    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

**CSS (index.css)**

```
/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeElement {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
}

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
}

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a;
}

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important;
}
```

**JS (index.js)**

```
// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh');

// Create an instance of Elements
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '18px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});
```

This displays the following...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the javascript in a onload event handler function.
Or have the `<script>` tags after the form declaration.